# Discord.js - how to edit bot command confirmation message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a code. this code replaces the letter "x" in the members' name with "y". but it sends the message I set for each user. that is, if there are 15 users, it sends the message "I changed the name of the x person" 15 times. I want to make this a single message then I want the bot to edit the message according to the user.
like this;
"I changed the name of `member` person" then "I changed the name of `member2` person. (edited)"?

```
exports.run =async (bot, message, args) => {
    let tokaci = message.guild.members.filter(membersx => {
        return membersx.roles.some(r=>["639572199409319994"].includes(r.id));
    });
   let tokacis = message.guild.members.filter(membersx => {
        return membersx.roles.some(r=>["tokuchi"].includes(r.name));
    }).size;
    tokaci.forEach(member => {
      if(!member.displayName.includes(`✯`)) return message.channel.send(`<:reds:669706016375701574> **Belirtilen role sahip kişilerin isminde değiştirilmesi gereken harfi bulamadım.**`)
        if(member.manageable) {
            let newNickName = member.displayName.replace(`✯`, '⛥');
            member.setNickname(newNickName)
            .catch(console.error)
          message.channel.send(`***<:onays:669706016354729984> Belirtilen role sahip olan kişilerin ismindeki harfi değiştiriyorum. ${member}***`)

        }
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another function to edit message or use `message.edit`. Method `channel.send()` return a promise with sended message.

```
exports.run =async (bot, message, args) => {
        let tokaci = message.guild.members.filter(membersx => {
            return membersx.roles.some(r=>["639572199409319994"].includes(r.id));
        });
       let tokacis = message.guild.members.filter(membersx => {
            return membersx.roles.some(r=>["tokuchi"].includes(r.name));
        }).size;
        message.channel.send('Start edit nicknemes').then(msg => {
        tokaci.forEach(member => {
          if(!member.displayName.includes(`✯`)) return message.channel.send(`<:reds:669706016375701574> **Belirtilen role sahip kişilerin isminde değiştirilmesi gereken harfi bulamadım.**`)
            if(member.manageable) {
                let newNickName = member.displayName.replace(`✯`, '⛥');
                member.setNickname(newNickName)
                .catch(console.error)
                let text = `***<:onays:669706016354729984> Belirtilen role sahip olan kişilerin ismindeki harfi değiştiriyorum. ${member}***`
                editMsg(msg,text)
            }
        });
        })

    }



    function editMsg(message, text) {
        message.edit(text)
    }
```

---

**V2**

```
exports.run =async (bot, message, args) => {
            let tokaci = message.guild.members.filter(membersx => {
                return membersx.roles.some(r=>["639572199409319994"].includes(r.id));
            });
           let tokacis = message.guild.members.filter(membersx => {
                return membersx.roles.some(r=>["tokuchi"].includes(r.name));
            }).size;
            message.channel.send('Start edit nicknemes').then(msg => {
            tokaci.forEach(member => {
              if(!member.displayName.includes(`✯`)) {
                    editMsg(msg,`***<:onays:669706016354729984> Belirtilen role sahip olan kişilerin ismindeki harfi değiştiriyorum. ${member}***`)
                  }
                if(member.manageable) {
                    let newNickName = member.displayName.replace(`✯`, '⛥');
                    member.setNickname(newNickName)
                    .catch(console.error)
                    let text = `***<:onays:669706016354729984> Belirtilen role sahip olan kişilerin ismindeki harfi değiştiriyorum. ${member}***`
                    editMsg(msg,text)
                }
            });
            })

        }



        function editMsg(message, text) {
            message.edit(text)
        }
```

Comment: thank you it's worked but its sending more times when member display name not includes 'x' how can I do that like this ?

Comment: I have adjusted the code.
if you want to edit another message, then you need to send some more message and do like `.then (msg2 => {`